# .htaccess redirect specific non existing files with query parameters to a new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an own domain which has urls with the url structure

```
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=12
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=12&id=1212122
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=15
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=15&id=121423
```

It has one or two query parameters in it. Now I want it to redirect to a new domain but with a different url structure like this.

```
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=12 -> https://www.newdomain.com/newurl_1/
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=12&id=1212122 -> https://www.newdomain.com/newurl_1/
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=15 -> https://www.newdomain.com/newurl_2/
https://www.olddomain.com/filename.php?cat=15&id=121423 -> https://www.newdomain.com/newurl_2/
```

It should redirect to a specific url depending on the "cat" query parameter. The "id" or any other query parameter/s after the "cat" is/are irrelevant.

Here's what I've done so far

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/filename.php [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=12(.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule . /newurl_1/ [L,NC,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The above code works half-fine except it adds the query parameters at the end of the new url like this

```
https://www.newdomain.com/newurl_1/?cat=12
https://www.newdomain.com/newurl_1/?cat=12&id=1212122
```

1. Can the additional query parameters be removed from the new url?
2. How do I extend my .htaccess for multiple different "cat" query parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 Yes, you need to add a `?` at the end of your rule:

```
RewriteRule . /newurl_1/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

as the query string is automatically appended, but with a `?`, it won't get appended unless you use the `QSA` flag.

As for 2., you'll need to write a rule for each cat parameter. You can do that or possibly look into using a `RewriteMap` (which doesn't work in an htaccess file). If you're going to enumerate through them all, you may want to adjust one of your conditions so it looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=12($|&) [NC]
```

So that it matches **12** and not something like **1234**

Comment: Thanks. The question no. 1 works. As for question number 2, I can't make it work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to solve question 2 as well. Thank you.